# Not being able to access inernet / DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET problem

Tags: networking, 20.04, dns

When i try to access any webpage, i get an DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET error:

[image: chrome error example]

It's not only on chrome, Discord and terminal acts strange too. I already tried to set 8.8.8.8 as my DNS server:

[image: network settings with DNS]

but it also haven't worked out(i also tried 1.1.1.1), and `systemd-resolve --status` sounds to be with the correct DNS:

```
Global
       LLMNR setting: no                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                  
      DNSSEC setting: no                  
    DNSSEC supported: no                  
  Current DNS Server: 8.8.8.8             
         DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8             
                      8.8.4.4
```

I have no idea what to do. I tried a lot of websites but none worked, and now i have to turn off and then turn on my network in order to access internet

Btw, I'm using ubuntu 20.04

**Edit:** Thomas asked me to run some tests:
I firstly ping for 10.0.0.1 (which it's my router's IP address) and it worked fine:

```
atheus@matheus:~$ ping -c 10 10.0.0.1
PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=30 time=1.79 ms
[...]
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=10 ttl=30 time=1.79 ms

--- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9012ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.781/1.891/2.187/0.121 ms
```

the same did to 8.8.8.8:

```
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9013ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 11.323/11.747/13.002/0.481 ms
```

but, after some time, i ran again and both haven't received anything:

```
--- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 9209ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 9206ms
```

I don't know why, but that is happening on my computer. When i turn off and then turn on my network, it works perfectly for 40 seconds, and then it stops working, giving those DNS errors. I'm currently having to turn off/on to be able to access internet and send this.

Comment: Let's start by doing some simple diagnostics.  Can you `ping -c 10 10.0.0.1`?  Can you `ping -c 10 8.8.8.8`?  Do you get failed packets or successful responses to pings?

Comment: @ThomasWard i just updated the post!

Comment: the DNS errors are because your computer stops communicating properly with the gateway and network.  Are you connected through a directly wired connection to the router, or do you hop through a switch or some other device?  Also, how old is this system (because a 100Mbps wired negotiation speed is... well, to put it simply 'not recent' in the networking hardware world)

Comment: @ThomasWard then that's something up with my Ubuntu, because it was perfectly working with this setup before, and i have a dual boot on this PC, with windows working fine, and i also tested with another windows laptop and also worked with no issued. Also, i don't see a need to get a higher speed, since my network is also 100mbps and it's fine